# laravel csrf tokens with Twig

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, twig

In Laravel the main app template has the following line

`<script>window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode(['csrfToken' => csrf_token(),]); ?></script>`

I'm using Twig for templates and need to change that line to work with Twig. However, I would have thought changing it to to

`<script>window.Laravel = {{ data|json_encode(['csrfToken': csrf_token(),]) }}</script>` or 
`<script>window.Laravel = {{ data|json_encode(['csrfToken' => csrf_token(),]) }}</script>`
would do the trick but it just errors. Whats the correct way to rewrite this?

Comment: What's `data` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct format should be:

```
<script>window.Laravel = {{ {'csrfToken': csrf_token()}|json_encode()|raw }}</script>
```

See for more info: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/json_encode.html

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as it gives the following output. `window.Laravel = {&quot;csrfToken&quot;:&quot;umq1L5R2rznr5hFJGrnAzqRH62soeQJ2lUub5kDs&quot;}`

Comment: @CraigWard I guess you need to chain it with `raw` filter then. I don't know what's your escaping startegy set. I updated my anwer.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick

`<script>window.Laravel = {"csrfToken":"{{csrf_token()}}"}</script>`

Comment: That's a really bad way to make JSONs :). You should always rely on `json_decode` to do proper escaping for you.